# Removing lines from one file based on non-existence in another

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I need to remove lines from fileA which has two columns if fileB (one column only) does not contain the string from column1 in fileA.

Example. Here is **fileA**:

```
a b
a c
a d
e f
g h
```

And **fileB**:

```
a
b
g
```

Here, the output should be:

```
a b
a c
a d
g h
```

Answer (score 5):

```
join fileA fileB
```

That assumes files are sorted on the first column (which they are in your example).

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'FNR == NR { onecol[$0]=1;next; }; $1 in onecol' fileB fileA
```

Comment: this seems to do what i need initially but it doesn't do it for all of lines. I have a file that is millions of lines (fileA in this case).

Comment: @hoda That seems to make little sense. What do the failing lines look like?

Comment: +1. Can be written as `'FNR==NR {a[$0]=1; next} $1 in a'`

Comment: `onecol[$1]` instantiates the array element with an empty value, so it's very inefficient. Better as `awk 'NR==FNR{onecol[$0];next}; $1 in onecol'`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if(NR==FNR) a[$1]=$1}{if($1==a[$1] && NR>FNR) print $0}' fileB.txt fileA.txt
```